# Base SDK Xcode 3.2.6

Tags: sdk, radix

Just wondering, I have created an application and ran it on an iPhone 3GS using Xcode 3.2.6. No problems there. Now, I'm trying to run the same application but on a 3G iPhone. I need to lower the base sdk to at least 4.1 however my only options are 4.3. I can manually enter a number within the info.plist however then I just get base sdk missing.

I have already tried changing the base sdk under the architecture pannel, as well as the ios deployment target.

how can i get base sdk to become 4.1 in xcode 3.2.6??

Thanks,
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

1. Please set the "Base SDK" to "Latest iOS", i.e. iOS 4.3 at this time.
2. Please set the "iOS Deployment Target" to the minimum iOS version you like, such as iOS 3.1.

Please get more details in the Xcode readme PDF file.